How do I differentiate between production builds and local builds for a nuget package
I am building a nuget package which will have a static frontend when packaged and distributed (working currently)
and during development it serves from the spa proxy of a dev server (working as well)
however, I am struggling to find a clean and concise way of differentiating between the packaged version of the application and the local version
I would like to know what the best way to achieve this is
in short, "How do I differentiate between production builds of a Nuget package and local builds"
something like below (but don't feel pressured to stick to this implementation if you feel there is a better way)
  public static IApplicationBuilder UseRulesEngineDashboard(
       this IApplicationBuilder app,
       Action<DashboardOptions> action = null!)
    {

        var options = new DashboardOptions();

        action?.Invoke(options);

        var env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
#if LOCAL_DEV
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(options.BaseUrl), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(options.ApiUrl);
            });
        });
#else
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(options.BaseUrl), builder =>
        {
                builder.UseStaticFiles("/" + options.BaseUrl);
                
        });

#endif
        return app;
    }


What's the issue with your version of that mentioned differentiation? To me personally having one #if PACKAGEBUILD ... #else ... seems as "clean and concise" as it can get.

I was hoping of a more practical way to orchestrate the process, truthfully I need to set quite a few different flags and constants for different things, and passing in various flags to dotnet run and alike doesn't bring me much joy, if this were a web app I could use something like a launch profile, but it's just a class library.
additionally having conditional blocks around my code like this I imagine can get quite unruly if the conditions were to get more complex, including different .net versions and whatnot

Hi @sebastianwhiffen, you can define custom build configurations in your project file (e.g., LocalDev and Production) and then use preprocessor directiveslike your code.

@Rena Hey, will these project directives be respected when built into a .nupkg ?
eg, if I pack the package like dotnet pack -p:DefineConstants="" will this remain empty for any subsequent uses as its packed self?
